# Intel Wifi Link 5100 - unstable connection

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, iwlwifi

i'd really love to move from windows to ubuntu, but there is a problem i have with my wireless connection. I have old Toshiba Satellite A300 with Intel Wifi Link 5100. I can see wireless networks and i can connect to them, but the connection is very unstable - it doesn't disconnect, rather connection to the web stops working. I don't know what is the problem, i tried to google it and tried some solutions posted here on askubuntu, but none of them worked.
I'm on 16.04 now, but i had this problem on 14.04 as well.

This particular thing really discourages me from using Ubuntu, sice i cannot use internet properly.

I would be really happy if someone with the same experience could tell me what to do.

Thanks in advance!

PS: I'm absolute layperson concerning Ubuntu and other linux distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I own and use successfully two Intel wireless devices. I have honed a few techniques in several years and thousands of forum posts.

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

If these changes do not help, please try:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=8
```

If it helps, make it permanent:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
exit
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply! I've completed every steps and it looks that it doesn't drop now. I noticed, however, that speed of my connection is slow on the laptop, even tho i sit right next to a router. On my desktop PC i have something like 30Mb/s download, on my laptop 10Mb/s (it's not a faulty router - my cellphone works flawlessly. But that is not that big deal since i can reliably connect into the web. Thanks a lot!